# Java sound sample processing with HZ

Tags: java, arrays, audio, javasound, sampling

Is it possible to cut samples from audio sample which are empty(too low hz) in a java program.

Idea is to get samples which can be combined together without a hearable  pause.

For example 
sample 1.audiofile says "one"
sample 2.audiofile says "two"

we combine then in a java program to say "onetwo" 
not "one      two".

I could not find anything which will get samples's hz value as Integer[]?